# curly braces in exp:channel-call?

Tags: channel-entries

I try to use this exp:channel:entries code to call a list of news for a year (YYYY), that is the third segment in the url … but it doesn’t work: the page is empty.

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="news" 
    limit="5" 
    year="{segment_3}" 
    orderby="date" 
    sort="desc" 
    paginate="bottom"
}
```

if I write "2016" or "2015" as a replacement for the {segment_3}, the code works without an error.

any ideas? 
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a parse order issue. Try adding `parse=inward` parameter to your channel call.